# Qt C++ limit system resources available to an application

Tags: c++, qt, resources

I'm working on a GUI application that uses a tab widget and has several tabs. I have one tab that has a table. I created a method to refresh the table every 5 seconds. Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::delay(int seconds)
{
    QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addSecs(seconds);
    while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime )
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}

void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int inx)
{
    if (inx == 3)
    {
        while (ui->tabWidget->currentIndex() == 3)
        {
            delay(5);
            refreshTable();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that ~30% of my CPU is being used up whenever the while loop is running. Basically the application is saying "Are we there yet? Are we there yet? Are we there yet?" and this seems to suck up the CPU.

Is there a way to limit the system resources, or some way to stop this from taking up a large portion of the CPU?

Comment: What you are doing is called polling. You are looking for a method that allows you to avoid polling. It looks like you could use the [QTimer class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtimer.html) to connect to your refreshTable function as a slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to bluebob for pointing me in the right direction. Here is my solution:

```
QTimer *timer;

void MainWindow::handleTableRefresh()
{
    if (ui->tabWidget->currentIndex() == 3)
    {
        refreshTable();
    }
    else
    {
        disconnect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(handleTableRefresh()));
        timer->stop();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int inx)
{
    if (inx == 3)
    {
        timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(handleTableRefresh()));
        timer->start(5000);
    }
}
```